# Is there a library function certain to sort your c# array in-place?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, mono

I have a small array that will be frequently sorted. My unity game is extremely allocation sensitive, so I'd rather have 0 allocations than save CPU cycles.

Array.Sort() causes allocations on unity's mono implementation on OSX. I can easily hand-write a sorter, but is there anything in the standard (.net 3.5) library that can do an alloc-free sort?

Comment: do you really need an array for that? maybe use a SortedSet?

Comment: Oh close, but not .net 3.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx